# how to get iphone push notifications working with lite version with separate app id

Tags: iphone, xcode, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm working on creating a "lite" version of my current app but am wondering the best way to implement the push notifications so that they work on both the lite version and the paid version. In xcode I duplicated the original target and have made my changes for the lite version using preprocessor codes but am now not sure how to setup the push notifications for the lite version. I currently have push notifications working for my paid version but am not sure how to get them to work for the lite version so that lite users can send notifications to paid users (it is my understanding that since both the lite version and the paid version have separate app ids that I will need separate push certificates?)??

Any help or guidance in the right direction would be greatly appreciate. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your application's have different AppIds, then you are correct that you will need to use different push certificates to push messages to the different applications.  The reasoning is that the push certificates are configured/enabled at the AppId level and are not reused between different AppIds.

In the scenario you described, you will need to identify which users are coming from the Lite version of the application versus the 'Paid' version.  Based on that distinction, you will be able to determine which push certificate to use when communicating with Apple's push services.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It was my understanding that I would need a different app id for my lite version. Is there another way to do this where the push certificates could be reused or is the method you described the only way to go about this?

Comment: I believe that Apple only allows one application per AppId.  Unfortunately I don't know a way around that restriction.  With other applications you could look into creating a wildcard AppId, however, Apple does not allow for push messaging to be enabled with a wildcard AppId.  This is one of those areas where developing iPhone applications becomes rather painful.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help. I've outlined a pretty good idea for how I will do this using your answer above. Thanks again for the clarification!